# Flutter Internationalize/Localize iOS not working XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I work currently on Internationalize/Localize of my App.

On Android everything is working. The Issue is with iOS. In the Flutter Docs there is said that you neeed to add the Languages in Info.plist, that's what i have done. But it changed nothing. I also added in the Project Runner -> Runner -> Info -> Localizations -> German and English(US) also in the info.plist -> Localized resources can be mixed - YES.

I tried only one of these settings, all of these settings but it is not working. The iOS Simulator is set to German as prefered Language.

[image: Runner Localizations]
[image: info.plist]
[image: Code]

Comment: Everything you do seems to be ok.
Do other system apps on your iOS simulator (Settings, Calendar etc.) use German?

Comment: Yes, everything else on the Simulator is on German

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The Problem was that on the iOS Simulator in the Language Setting there is German and German(Germany). I used German but you need to use German(Germany).